# If I queue with my friends who were in the same rank as me last season and play all my placements, will we be placed in the same rank?

Tags: overwatch

So my friends and I have a big time zone difference and we want to play competitive with each other. However, Season 7 has started, and we need to do our placements. But if we get placed in different ranks, we won't be able to play with each other.

If I queue with them, would I get placed in the same rank as them?

Comment: "But if we get placed in different ranks, we won't be able to play with each other" Are you sure about this? I seem to remember playing with my high ranking friends while being quite bad myself

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Placement ranks at the end of the 10 calibration matches are based on (from experience) final SR from the previous season, individual performance during the calibration matches, difference in the party's SR, and possibly more factors that Blizzard hasn't disclosed.

For season 6, it was possible for a party of players in the same rank to play all 10 calibration matches together and end up in different ranks. Note that this is also possible during normal matches: SR change after each match won't necessarily be the same for players in the same party.

Comment: This is correct. I've personally had experiences where two people queuing for first placements ended up being almost 1000 SR difference. If one player is having lots of trouble and barely gets any kills or even throwing the game and the other person is carrying the team, getting all gold medals, on fire the entire match, ect they will be placed at wildly different rankings.

Comment: True story. I played my 10 matched last seasson got to 3200. decayed down to 3000. lost 9 matched this season got placed 3043 ...